# Web logic domain page is not open

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, weblogic12c, weblogic11g

i am newbie about web logic parts. I have created web logic server and when i want to create a domain not giving error but not appear any screen just shown 2 second and not open page.

I am texting this cmd

> C:\Users\asus>%WL_HOME%\common\bin\config.cmd

[image]

It's showing 2 second and not open more page.

Which part i am doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: when i get log writing com.oracle.cie.wizard.internal.wcf.WCFWrapper - Overriding task definition summary_gui